# Android: Weird scrolling problems with ListView

Tags: android, listview, scroll

I am using a ListView to display several items(TextViews).
The ListView is filled with an adapter.

This is all I do with the ListView in the Fragment.

```
mLV = (ListView) mRootView.findViewById(R.id.session_list);
mLV.setAdapter(SessionManager.getInstance(getActivity().getApplicationContext()));
mLV.setDivider(new ColorDrawable(Color.RED));
mLV.setDividerHeight(400);
mLV.setBackground(new ColorDrawable(Color.YELLOW));
```

This is the XML definition:

```
<ListView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/session_list"
    style="@style/main.list"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">
</ListView>
```

However the scrolling behaves weird.
If I am at the top of the list and want to scroll down it does not work, unless i pull the list up beforehand and then scroll down in one motion.
This happens everytime when i start scrolling from the top of the list.
When starting anywhere else it works fine.

Comment: is the `ListView` the only thing in your `Fragment`?

Comment: Still happens if you remove the `mLV.setDividerHeight(400);` line?

Comment: Its part of a ViewPager. but the only thing on the screen. 
Implementation of ViewPager almost matches this example http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/lateral.html

Comment: @nKn thanks. That causes the problem. if I start scrolling in the upper part it works. Just had that in there to figure out why my divider isn't shown (still didn't found it)

Comment: It probably has to do with the specified size, 400 is a huge size!